# trying to connect nodejs to lando mysql but fails

Tags: mysql, node.js, lando

Im trying to connect nodejs to mysql running from lando..
db is up and running...

any other non nodejs project (non node js) i can connect without issues

does anyone have an idea why this might happen?
am i missing something?

**My nodejs connection**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

const mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'database',
    user: 'lemp',
    password: 'lemp',
    database: 'lemp',
    port: 3306
});
```

**my lando config:**

```
services:
  database:
    type: mysql
    creds:
      username: lemp
      password: lemp
```

**my DB from terminal**

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| lemp               |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use lemp
Database changed
```

**output**

```
$ node index.js
Server listening on port 8080
/home/maarten/www/react/test/server/index.js:19
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN database
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/maarten/www/react/test/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/maarten/www/react/test/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/maarten/www/react/test/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/maarten/www/react/test/server/index.js:18:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  errno: -3001,
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'database',
  fatal: true
}

Node.js v18.19.0
```

❯ node -v
v18.19.0
❯ npm -v
10.2.3

tried internal and localhost as mysql host in nodejs but does noet work

Comment: that has nothing to do with programming, your local dns doesn't know the server database, if you have installed the mysql server on the same machine, use local host, if not you need o read up on mysql accessing from lan

Comment: EAI_AGAIN is a DNS lookup timed out error, means it is a network connectivity error or proxy related error. do you use a VM or are you trying to dockerise the app? ?

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out...
needed to run both client and server with lando command.
$ lando npm run start and $ lando node index.js